# C# script in XSLT: "msxsl:script cannot be empty" error

Tags: c#, xslt

I have an XSLT with a C# script in it:

```
<msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="user">
  <msxsl:using namespace="System.Xml"/>
  <msxsl:using namespace="System.Xml.XPath"/>
  <![CDATA[
    public string GetMenuPath(XPathNodeIterator node)
    {       
      XPathNavigator dataSourceNode = node.Current;
      return dataSourceNode.Name;
    }
  ]]>
</msxsl:script>
```

And somewhere in the XSLT this function is called:

```
<xsl:value-of select="user:GetMenuPath(current())"/>
```

But as I try to run the XSLT transformation on the XML input (the input does not matter), it stop immediately with the error "msxsl:script cannot be empty".

I have absolutely no idea why... I use nxslt with .NET Framework.

Thank you for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your answers, I found out the origin of the problem now. It was because I was using the "style" tag instead of "nxslt" for calling the XSLT transformation. "style" works as long as there is no extension script.

```
<nxslt style="transformation.xsl" in="input.xml" out="output.xls" verbose="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it give you the line that the transformation stops on? Is it where it is calling from or in the script tag?

Comment: No, so I tried to run it with the XSLT debugger of Visual Studio, and the transformation worked !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting your extension method into a separate assembly and referencing it that way?

Marc

Comment: No, but this was not the cause, since it worked when running it in Visual Studio. But I found it out now !